# CoinGecko exchange rates conversion

Tags: coingecko

I already seen the CoinGecko documentation but it does not contain explaination or in depth explaination on their API [Documentation](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api).

Regarding on CoinGeckos API, their is `exchange_rates` but it is only applicable for Bitcoin (BTC) to other currencies, my concern is, is there a ways to make any conversion from XRP to AUD base on this response?
`https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/exchange_rates`

Also they have a link to make [conversion](https://www.coingecko.com/en/coins/xrp/aud#:%7E:text=XRP%20to%20AUD%20rate%20for%20today%20is%20A%240.920100.) but I don't know how they make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution

The API returns an object with the list of rates:

```json
{
  "rates": {
    "btc": {
      "name": "Bitcoin",
      "unit": "BTC",
      "value": 1,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "eth": {
      "name": "Ether",
      "unit": "ETH",
      "value": 15.108,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "ltc": {
      "name": "Litecoin",
      "unit": "LTC",
      "value": 243.364,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "bch": {
      "name": "Bitcoin Cash",
      "unit": "BCH",
      "value": 66.392,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "bnb": {
      "name": "Binance Coin",
      "unit": "BNB",
      "value": 114.554,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "eos": {
      "name": "EOS",
      "unit": "EOS",
      "value": 8665.498,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "xrp": {
      "name": "XRP",
      "unit": "XRP",
      "value": 50657.684,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
    "xlm": {
      "name": "Lumens",
      "unit": "XLM",
      "value": 131419.329,
      "type": "crypto"
    },
   ...
}
```

So inorder to get the currency value for XRP to AUD, it needs to divide the 2 values, example  AUD 45686.711 / XRP 50657.684 <s>where the dividen should be the highest value</s>

Sorry my bad, the conversion should be `$to / $from` there is no dividen format

Can someone confirm this as a solution?